# Get Input Value From Datatables

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>RM Code</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Wh</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Quantity
                <br>Recipe</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="details">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="code[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="wh[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

how to get quantity value from datatables above.
and I have tried

```
$('#table tbody').on('change', 'td', function(e) {
    alert(dtable.cell(this).data());
});
```

I still can't get value from my input field..

Comment: Where's database connectivity and PHP code?

Comment: input type text can't be in array. you should use checkbox instead

Comment: @SKR _“input type text can't be in array”_ - why not? Was this supposed to be a comment specific to some issue with datatables, or …? Because in general, it is of course absolutely not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two solutions for you. The first which actually goes with your approach. However, it is not suitable since the user receives an alert when any of the input fields in a table row gets change, thus, not the quantity field only

```
  $('#table tbody').on('change', 'td', function(e) {
   var data = $('td').find('input[name="qty[]"]').val();
   alert(data);
});
```

The second, which is more convenient. The user receives an alert only when the quantity field is changed. With this, you need to add a class to the quantity table data as

```
<td class="price">
     <input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" />
   </td>
```

the handle it as

```
 $('#table tbody').on('change', 'td.price', function(e) {
   var data = $(this).find('input').val();
   alert(data);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = dtable.row(this).nodes().to$().find('input[name="rm_code[]"]').val();
```